# Position of div after jQuery.show();

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get a div to show up in the correct place after using jQuery's .show().

In the image below, you can see the search div (autocomplete div) shows up to the far left, but I want it to show up where I drew the red box.

[image]

Basically I have a small header in the center of my site 1000px in width, and when the autocomplete div shows up, I'd like it to be lined up in the right place, but I'm not sure how set margins or anchors to get it to be in the right spot.

**Here is my JS:**

```
    $('#sbar').focus(function(){
        $('#acd').show();
    });
```

Here is the CSS for the autocomplete DIV:

```
.autoCompleteDiv{
    width: 428px;
    height: 150px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 66px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: small;
    color: gray;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.93;
```

Basically I want to move the div into the red spot, but have it compatible between screen sizes, and have it stay lined up when the window is 'windowed'.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Regards

Comment: your position:fixed will make it fixed to the browser window, which defaults to `left:0` , try removing the position:fixed, and use position:relative instead

Comment: `show()` will simply give the element display:block, and your position fixed needs a left value too ...

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of the display:block given to it by .show(). I want it to remain fixed when scrolling however, so wouldn't position:relative not do that?

What left value should I give my position: fixed? If I gave it 500px, wouldn't this change as the window's dimensions change size? I.e. the autocomplete div would always be 500px left of the window's left edge.

Comment: Position: Relative inserts a space between the header and my body. Fixed with a left value changes its alignment when the window is resized.

Comment: Essentially my question is how can I position this div such that its anchored to be in line with the header in the right position, and stays fixed on top of everything, unchanging when the window is resized?

Comment: just give it a css `left` property and it will shift to the right

Comment: No, that won't work, because I need it to remain aligned during window resizing... for the 10th time

Answer (score 0):

If you use the search div as a container for your auto complete div, then it should show in 
place. I have created a [quick demo](http://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/FlAmy) that illustrates this.

the html looks like this:

```
<div id="search"><input value="search" type="text"/>
    <div id="auto"><p>autocomplete</p></div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
#search{position:fixed;top:20px;left:200px;}
#auto{display:none;width:auto;min-height:100px;}
```

To make it responsive, simply use media queries to update the position of the search box...

hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Made a 1000px container div with:

```
#acdContainer {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 150px;
    top: 64px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And changed my auto-complete div to be:

```
.autoCompleteDiv{
    width: 730px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px;
    z-index: 999;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: Raleway;
    font-size: small;
    color: gray;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    display: none;
}
```

So that the autocomplete div saw itself as being in a 1000px window, which was always centered.